# Navigating Power BI's DirectQuery Dynamics: Understanding Query Execution and Data Retrieval from BigQuery

Tags: powerbi

As a newcomer to Power BI, I'm currently utilizing DirectQuery to connect to a BigQuery database, which houses a substantial amount of data. My current approach involves executing a query where the datetime is greater than a specific date, such as:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE(insertDateTime) AS insertDateTime,
  customer,
  Type,
  market
FROM
  `table`
WHERE
  market = 'India'
  AND Type ='CUSTCREATE'
  AND DATE(insertDateTime) > '2024-01-30'
```

In my report, I've incorporated slicers for user interaction. However, upon examining the queries sent from Power BI to BigQuery when the report is accessed, I've observed multiple queries varying significantly in size, ranging from 5GB to 50GB.

This phenomenon prompts me to question whether Power BI initially retrieves all data from January 30, 2024, onwards and subsequently applies slicer data, thus necessitating clarification.

Is it correct to assume that keeping the WHERE clause in my query is the appropriate approach, or should I consider removing it? Would removing the WHERE clause fetch all the data from BigQuery?